# Result about Convergent Subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my lecture notes I have a proof of the following:

> Let $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ be subsequences of $(a_n)$. If $(a_{2n})\to l$ and $(a_{2n+1})\to l$ then $(a_n)\to l$.

By definition, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a positive integer $N'%$ such that  $|a_{2n}-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N'$. However, for $\epsilon>0$ there also exists another positive integer $N''$ such that $|a_{2n+1}-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N''$.

Now let $N=\max\{2N'+1,2N''+2\}$ and for all $n>N$, $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$. So $a_n$ converges to $l$.

Now, I have trouble understanding this last bit. For what reason did the lecturer choose $N=\max\{2N'+1,2N''+2\}$ and why for this $N$, $n>N\implies |a_n-l|<\epsilon$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because if $n > N$, then you can write $n = 2k$ or $n = 2k+1$ with $k > N'$ resp. $k > N''$.